# Set Dapper Object different from Column name in SQL

Tags: c#, sql, dapper

I used to work with Entity Framework but recently moved over to Dapper. One feature I liked about EF is that I can give an attribute to an object telling it, this is the column you are looking for.

For example:

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "USER_CODE")]

public int ID {get;set;}
```

Dapper reads the database with `USER_CODE`, but I can see the object as `ID`.

Does anyone know if something like this is possible in DAPPER?

Answer (score 4):

There is extensions for this situation which is named fluent-mapper. You can check it from [here](https://github.com/henkmollema/Dapper-FluentMap). I hope it hels.

Or you can use like

```
List<User> user = conn.Query<User>("SELECT USER_CODE as ID, ... FROM USERS....").ToList();
```